# iOS Firebase Crash Reporting Uploading Symbol files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I integrated the firebase crash reporting into my app via cocoa pods . I created the run script ext.

So it is working now. But my problem is, every time I try to build and run the app even in the simulator it tries to upload Symbol files and it takes too much time to build and run the app.

I used hockey app before. And in hockey app i am using hockey app's mac application to upload the symbol file when i want to. For example when my development and developer tests finish then i am releasing add hoc build then i am sending symbol files to hockey app.

So my question is: What is the best use case flow of the firebase crash reporting? Can i upload symbol files before i release add hoc or App Store release? (Not every time)

Or is it possible to disable the "run script" for symbol file upload in the simulator builds.

Answer (score 5):

So I just keep the "Run script only when installing" checked on my symbol upload run script.

This ensures that it will only get run when archiving the app, and not during development (e.g. when releasing our app into the wild).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I thought I'd bust this guy, thinking "Run script only when installing" would also trigger when installing build on device, but nope, this works only during archive. I'm not sure what's the logic behind that checkbox, but this is a valid answer!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are looking for something like this:

```
if [ ${PLATFORM_NAME} != "iphonesimulator" ]; then
    echo "Uploading Firebase Crash Symbols..."

    # Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
    GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

    # Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
    "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
fi
```

So, at the very least, it only runs and uploads symbols when you are building for anything that isn't the simulator.

Comment: Thanks this is good answer. But it cannot solve my problem. Because i have 2 configuration 1 is debug and 1 is release. Debug is connecting to test and release is connecting to production environment. 
So i am also sending test - addhoc builds and it needs to be trackable. So my questions is i just want to prevent to send symbol files when i am using simulator. Is it possible?

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense, yes. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This would upload symbols only for `release` build configuration:

```
echo configuration is $CONFIGURATION

if [ $CONFIGURATION == Release ]; then

    echo uploading symbols

    # Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
    GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:************

    # Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
    "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}/GoogleServiceAccount.json"

else

    echo skipping symbols upload

fi
```

Comment: not helping on my environment. When I run release mode xcode hungs it self running the custom shell script. In Dev mode everything works fine

Comment: @Kingalione you might want to check your build log. Bash's if-then is unlikely to hang something.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to run the script every time if you don't want to.  Minimally, you should run once for each build that's going to the store.  You can upload before the app is released to the store.

Comment: So you are suggesting; delete the run script and add it when you do the add hoc and app store release. Did i understand correctly?
But i need to automate this flow. Is it possible?

Comment: You don't have to delete anything. Just run it manually or from some other script only during the times when it's required.